# Expatriate leaving France: Who should I notify (taxes/etc) that I'm moving out?

Tags: france, taxes, legal

I'm from Brazil and I was living in France from July 2016 until January 2018.
I was working in the private sector with a titre de séjour, and now I just moved to Germany. So ideally everything needs to be done online or by letter (and French companies love letters, right? lol).

Who should I inform legally that I left the country? Taxes department (impôts)? How?

I already cancelled my cellphone, bank account and dealt with the landlord and gas/energy companies.

Thanks so much, hope someone can help me with that!

Answer (score 5):

You have to notify the tax authorities of your change of address. You still owe them money (taxes for 2017 and one month of 2018), and they want to keep in touch until no mores taxes are due.

Ref: https://www.impots.gouv.fr/portail/particulier/questions/je-pars-vivre-letranger-quelles-demarches-dois-je-accomplir-dois-je-cloturer